# Div width automatically sizes to the width of its contents within a div which has a set width?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Lets say I have this

```
<div class="sectionContainer">
    <div class="itemsContainer">
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
        <div class="items"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.itemsContainer 
{
 /* width:3000px works, however this is what I want to avoid saying explicitly.*/
}

.sectionContainer
{
width: 1000px;
overflow: auto; 
}

.items
{
width: 1000px;     
float: left;     
}
```

The sectionContainer has some set width.

The items has some set width.

The items container does not have a set width; it will scale to the size of its contents.
The items container's overflow is set to hidden, so that one can scroll through the items within the div. **The items within the div are horizontally displayed** IE they are side-by-side, I'm currently doing this with a float.

How can I do this with CSS only? Is it possible? I'm not looking for a JavaScript solution right away but can resort to that if needed.

to be more specific, this would work if I specified the itemsContainer to have a width of 3000. But I'm guessing that since it is the child of its parent div, its width gets sized to 1000. I do not want to explicitly set the size of the itemsContainer because this should be based upon the number of items. If I add more items, I want the itemsContainer to change its width to contain all of those items without having to alter the CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: this question bounced over my head :p and btw whats this? `items has some set width.` and the next line `The items container does not have a set width;`

Comment: What is your problem actually? You don't have a scrollbar or your itemsContainer does not resize itself (if so you'll need to place a clear:both before the div ends)?

Comment: can you post the CSS that you have so far?

Comment: @Mr.Alien look again at my code now i have updated the post.

Comment: @Caelea not sure how to get the itemsContainer div to resize based upon the size of its contents, so that it contains all of its contents horizontally, while being within a div with a set width.

Comment: Can't be done without explicit width declaration of the parent...whether you set it, or JavaScript does it: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#floating-elements

Comment: @Dawson okay. This just tells me a float will wrap. That's not what I want. Is there another way to make my elements display horizontally without floating them all left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for CSS to guess what you want to happen -- meaning that it wants to cascade elements downward as opposed to horizontally, which is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/9NHFa/

Set the itemsContainer width to a 100% X the number of elements.

```
.itemsContainer 
{
width:300%; /* since you have 3 elements
}
```

Comment: Hm, then how is it possible that some divs can infact resize themselves to the contents without CSS? For example, without setting the container div's width, you can clearly see that the itemcContainer's size now has adjusted itself to fit all of its contents within it... http://jsfiddle.net/WqysJ/4/

Comment: `div`s are block elements -- their default width is 100% of their parent, which is why your width-less `div`s are stacking vertically...they're supposed to...they don't leave room to the right for the next element (even when they're `float`ing).

Comment: they are not stacking vertically. They are horizontal.

Comment: same fiddle, but with jQuery counting children to assign % width: http://jsfiddle.net/9NHFa/1/

Comment: Your **original code** (in FF) was stacking items 1,2,3 on top of one another, as one would expect. The original code had three elements the same width as their Grand-parent container (parent container width not set); thus `parent` width will default to its parent...1000px. Placing children of 1000px inside that parent (regardless of `float`) will NOT allow them to float to the right of the first-child because there isn't an additional 1000px left for them to exist within.

Comment: look at my update. See the piece of code which I commented out. See how i say, if I set this explicitly, then it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/WqysJ/6/

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But how does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/WqysJ/4/

Comment: .sectionContainer is taking the width of its parent (`<body>`), .itemsContainer is taking .sectionContainer's width. So as long as `<body>` is wider than those 5 kids...they'll float horizontally. Squish the window -- you'll see what I mean.

Comment: this does exactly what I want. I dont know how or why, but I'm able to just specify an arbitrarily large container size, and it automatically will only overflow to the size of its content. http://jsfiddle.net/WqysJ/7/